# IPv6 and Messengers

Tags: networking, tcp, xmpp, ipv6

Does anyone know if messengers like Whatsapp/Yahoo/Gtalk/XMPP supports IPv6? Surprisingly I couldn't find any reliable information on this anywhere on internet.

If we want to launch new messaging server on internet we need to make it IPv6 ready (As IPv4 address space is almost running out). Is it possible to listen on same port for both IPv4 and IPv6 ?

Elaborated inputs/discussion would help for everyone who wants to launch new servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatsapp, Yahoo and Gtalk are services. As far as I know Whatsapp does not support IPv6 (at the moment). Gtalk does support IPv6, and I *think* Yahoo does as well.

XMPP is a protocol, and there are many implementations. Some that I know support IPv6 are (in nu particular order):

- [Openfire (previously Wildfire)](http://www.jivesoftware.org/)
- [ejabberd](http://ejabberd.jabber.ru/)
- [Prosody](http://prosody.im/)
- [Jabberd](http://jabberd2.org/)

And I am sure there are many more :)